# Understanding a property of $\Omega^*(U)$ (differential forms theory)

Tags: real-analysis

If $U$ is a vector space then the function
$d: \Omega^*(U) \rightarrow  \Omega^*(U)$ has the following properties:

- $df = \sum_{i= 1}^2 \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ if $f \in \Omega^0(U) $
- $d(f\alpha) = df\cdot\alpha + f\cdot d\alpha$, $f\in \Omega^0(U), \alpha \in \Omega^*(U)$
- $d \circ d = 0 \implies d \restriction_{\Omega^1(U)} = 0$

Now, I don't understand the implication in third property. For example, if you have $f\,dx \in \Omega^1(U)$  with $f \in \Omega^0(U) $ And you compute $d(f\,dx) = df\,dx \ne 0$

Comment: Yes, this doesn't make sense. What's the context?

Answer (score 1):

One always has $d\circ d=0$ but obviously $d$ can be nonzero on $1$-forms; for example $d$ of $xdy$ is nonzero.  However if $U$ is a $1$-dimensional domain then $d$ will be zero on $1$-forms.  Perhaps this is what is meant.

Comment: yes this is also what I thought, I think it might just be not well written